# How to properly encode a long text to utf-8 properly in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

We can encode a text to utf-8 using this method

```
print u"\u221A".encode('utf-8')
```

But, how we can encode a text which is like this ?

```
[<p>d = \u221a2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl\u221ah</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]
```

The above text is an output data from scraping a web page. It may contain a multiline text or single-line text.

After scraping multiple HTML text we are storing it in a list.

Comment: What is `[<p>d = \u221a2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl\u221ah</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]` supposed to be? It's not valid Python syntax for anything. Did you scrape a web page and extract 4 snippets of its HTML into a list? Do you have the raw text `[<p>d = \u221a2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl\u221ah</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]` sitting in a file somewhere? Something else?

Comment: You say "a long text", but it's not clear whether this thing is actually supposed to be a single piece of text. (Yes, this matters.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes above mentioned text is a scraped html and stored in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your ultimate goal is to convert

```
[<p>d = \u221a2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl\u221ah</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]
```

into

```
[<p>d = √2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl√h</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]
```

There is an easy way to achieve this , using the "codecs" module (documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html)

Code :

```
import codecs
obj = '[<p>d = \u221a2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl\u221ah</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]'
codecs.encode(obj, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
print(obj)
```

Output :

```
[<p>d = √2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl√h</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]
```

Comment: Just a note: Run this with python3 then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.

Just add "u" before this string and it will give you expected output.

```
print u"[<p>d = \u221a2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl\u221ah</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]".encode('utf-8')
```

Output is

```
[<p>d = √2RH</p>, <p>d = 2Rlh</p>, <p>d = 2Rl√h</p>, <p>d = 2Rh</p>]
```

Waiting for someone else's answer to check if someone is having a good and efficient code compared to my code.

Comment: You said you have a list, not a string. You can't just stick `u` before a list. Sticking `u` in front is part of the Python 2 syntax for Unicode string literals; it only works with string literals, not lists, and not even strings computed at runtime, like any scraping output would be.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, i am still facing problem with this. My answer isn't working good. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: I suspect what you need doesn't actually have anything to do with UTF-8. It's hard to tell, though; we don't have enough context. It sounds like your real goal here is to get those square root characters to display as square root characters instead of as backslash escapes; is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to show square root characters.

Comment: The backslash escapes are coming from the strings' `repr`, which is invoked by the list's `str` implementation to avoid ambiguity. To avoid that, you need to avoid printing the list directly. What you need to do instead depends on why you were printing the list in the first place instead of passing it to some other data processing stage or sending output to a file or something.

Comment: You may need to encode and print the strings individually, or build a single, combined string, or something else.